# Missing /v8 variant from linux/arm64 platform

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-buildkit

I'm using buildx for my multiarch Docker build.

The base image `python:3.8.5-alpine` has `linux/arm64/v8` as one of its OS/archs, but the resulting image ([`corralpeltzer/newtrackon`](https://hub.docker.com/r/corralpeltzer/newtrackon/tags)) has the variant `/v8` missing, creating an image with `linux/arm64` in its manifest.

I'm confused about this difference. Will it create compatibility issues? Should I try to force the variant with [`docker manifest annotate`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/#manifest-annotate)?

For more details, this is ran inside a [GitHub action](https://github.com/CorralPeltzer/newTrackon/runs/900004362). This is part of the buildx command:

```
buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8
```

This issue seems to come from what archs are available to the buildx builder:

```
/usr/bin/docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 1.6s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_builder-4bebce7d838a55e24aa111384fec8c97144df7290
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_builder-4bebce7d838a55e24aa111384fec8c97144df7290 1.7s done
#1 DONE 3.3s
Name:   builder-4bebce7d838a55e24aa111384fec8c97144df729
Driver: docker-container

Nodes:
Name:      builder-4bebce7d838a55e24aa111384fec8c97144df7290
Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Status:    running
Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```